# Jsch Exception: Auth Fail with private key

Tags: ssh, private-key

I'm using below code to connect remote server and I followed below steps to connect private/public key generation & concatenate of public key with authorized key.

**Code:**

```
private Session createSession() throws JSchException {
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
            jsch.addIdentity(privateKey);                   //add private key path as ~/.ssh/id_rsa
            Session session;
            session = jsch.getSession(user, host, port);
            java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();

        Properties cfg = new Properties();
            cfg.put("trust", "true");
            cfg.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            cfg.put("HashKnownHosts", "yes");

            session.setConfig(cfg);
            session.connect();
            return session;
    }
```

**Steps:**

```
1. I can able to generate private/public key in the path ~/.ssh/id_rsa(private key) and ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub(public key)
    >> ssh-keygen (or) ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096
   Note: Generated key with no passphrase
2. I have added public key with authorized_keys with below command
    >> ssh user@host "echo \"`cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`\" >> .ssh/authorized_keys"
```

Still I'm facing the exception "com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail". Please guide me to proceed.

Answer (score 4):

I believe this can happen for several reasons:

- The private key is password protected, which you have already verified is not the case.
- The directory containing the keys is encrypted.
- The file permissions on the .ssh directory and or public/private keys are too open.  They should be:

  - ssh directory: 700
  - public key: 644
  - private key: 600 (possibly even 400)
- What also might be going on is the format of the public key within the authorized keys file is incompatible.  You might need to convert it to a different format.  Assuming OpenSSH:

  - Convert to SSH2:

    `ssh-keygen -i -f /path/to/private/key
    ssh-keygen -i -f /path/to/public/key`
  - Convert from SSH2:

    `ssh-keygen -e -f /path/to/private/key
    ssh-keygen -e -f /path/to/public/key`

Comment: I had Jsch successfully authenticate once. Then I re-did keygen and udpated keys everywhere and now I'm getting the error above too

Comment: Changing private key from 600 to 400 fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

JSch does not support rsa-sha2. And as JSch seems not to be updated anymore, it quite likely never will.
Try this **ssh-keygen -m PEM -t rsa -b 2048** its work.

Comment: Jcraft hasn't updated since 2018, but a fork in https://github.com/mwiede/jsch is current and includes rsa-sha2-# signatures -- _and_ 'new' format keyfiles (OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY), which Jcraft's 1.55 does not, and is the _only_ thing you changed by `-m PEM` (exactly the same RSA keys, in either old or new format, can be used for both rsa-sha2-# and ssh-rsa signatures in OpenSSH, except in 8.8 up ssh-rsa is disabled by default and must be reenabled).